# Как отсортировать std::map по значению?

Tags: c++, c++11

Допустим есть

```
std::map<string, int> MyMap;
```

**Как вывести содержимое контейнера, начиная с наибольшего значения?**
Сам контейнер дальше не используется.

Comment: Что такое в данном случае "значение"?

Comment: У контейнера есть ключ, а есть значение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```
map<string, int> MyMap;
MyMap["3"] = 30;
MyMap["1"] = 10;
MyMap["2"] = 20;
MyMap["4"] = 0;

for (pair<string, int> pair : MyMap) {
    cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << '\n';
}
cout << '\n';

map<int, string> reverseMyMap;
for (pair<string, int> pair : MyMap) {
    reverseMyMap[pair.second] = pair.first;
}

cout << "Reverse:\n";
map<int, string>::reverse_iterator it = reverseMyMap.rbegin();
while (it != reverseMyMap.rend()) {
    cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << '\n';
    it++;
}
```

Консоль:

```
1: 10
2: 20
3: 30
4: 0

Reverse:
30: 3
20: 2
10: 1
0: 4
```

Comment: Плохо, потому, что значения могут совпадать: `{{"1", 1}, {"2", 1}}`

Comment: ну тогда просто стоит заменить `map`, на `multimap`, делов то

Comment: В целом так и сделал

Answer (score 0):

Выполнить итерирование не от `.begin()` до `.end()`, а от  `.rbegin()` до `.rend()` - словом, воспользоваться `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: Нужно отсортировать по ЗНАЧЕНИЮ! А не по ключу.

Comment: Тогда используйте другой контейнер, в который поместите указатели (чтоб сэкономить память) на элементы вашего `map`, отсортируйте его соответствующим образом и выводите. Непосредственно пересортировать `map`, да еще сделав из него `multimap`, способа не имеется.

Answer (score 0):

Если пересортировка выполняется достаточно часто, то лучше использовать [`boost::multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/index.html) с [`ordered_unique`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#unique_non_unique) по `std::string` и `ordered_non_unique` по `int`.